# requests.get() method times out even though website is clearly online

Tags: python-3.x, http, python-requests, bots

So, I've decided I want to brush up on my programming skills by learning a new language and starting to build bots. "hackthissite.org" has several programming challenges that I want to complete. The first one is to unscramble some words.

Ok, simple enough. Let me create a script that logs in and isolates the words first.

I can't seem to connect to the  site in under 15 seconds. I'm using the "Requests" API to do this. Here is my code:

```
def main():
print("Starting Prograam")
session = requests.session()
session = requests.get("https://www.hackthissite.org/pages/index/index.php")
print(str(session.status_code))
print("Successfully Connected to the site") #TODO: Error Handling
login = {'username' : 'My Account Username', 'password' : 'Terrible Hard-coded Password Here'}
session = requests.post("https://www.hackthissite.org/user/login", data=login)
bs = BeautifulSoup(session.content, "html.parser")
print(bs.prettify())

main()
```

The program runs for eleven years and I just end up getting either a timeout error or wait a ridiculous amount of time that I know I shouldn't be waiting. I can't seem to find anyone on the internet with the same problem as me. Is it something "hackthissite.org" has against bots? Do I need to mask my activity as a user in some way?

Answer (score 0):

You never use the session you first create so all lines bar the last two are irrelevant, to login all you need is your username, password and to set the *referer* header to https://www.hackthissite.org:

```
def main():
    print("Starting Program")
    with  requests.session() as session:
        login = {"username": "username",
                 "password": "pass",
                 "btn_submit": "Login"}
        session.headers.update({"referer":"https://www.hackthissite.org"})
        s = session.post("https://www.hackthissite.org/user/login", data=login)
        bs = BeautifulSoup(s.content, "html.parser")
        print(bs.prettify())
```

Once you do you will see your profile page in the output.

Comment: Ok, now I'm logging in consistently, but only after something like 15 seconds. What gives? I can log in manually faster than that.